# 301 Redirects with Silex or Nginx - Advantages/Disadvantages?

Tags: redirect, nginx, silex

I am about to upload a new version of a website and am looking to add 301 redirects from the old paths to new ones.

The website uses Silex with Nginx, so I am trying to decide whether to do the redirects with Silex or in the Nginx config file. Are there any differences between these two methods?

I have very little understanding of the topic so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always better to let the server do the jobs it is intended for.

For the sake of resources on the machine, you should let nginx handle this: imagine your app having to process 500 redirects in a minute, you'd have to call the whole silex stack before you get to redirect the request.

You could find some insights here : http://www.tinywp.in/301-redirect-wordpress/

It's applied to wordpress but the way he ends up writing his redirect rules for nginx seems efficient, as said, it spares the server the hassle to evaluate a regular expression:

```
server{
   server_name www.domain.com
   return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the perfect answer. Sorry I didn't respond before.